# getresponse api

Tags: php, api, curl

Доброго времени суток. Суть проблемы такова. Есть аккаунт на getresponse. Нужно использовать их API 360. 
 Для авторизации требуют API KEY и Domain Name переданными в заголовке. Я пытался сам написать CURL функцию через которую вызывал нужный мне метод API на что получал реально пустоту. Без каких либо ответов с сервера. 
После побывал использовать готовое решения https://github.com/GetResponse/getresponse-api-php 
Делал все как в примере, в ответ пустота.

Вот код моего примера:

```
  $getresponse = new GetResponse('api key');
  $getresponse->enterprise_domain = 'мой домен';
  $getresponse->api_url = 'https://api3.getresponse360.com/v3';

  $result = $getresponse->accounts();
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($result);
  echo '</pre>';
```

В ответ пусто(

Comment: Забыл сказать. Сервер настроен правильно. Стоит php5-curl, стоят так же php5-json и соответственно работают запросы с "вне".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Николай, попробуйте изменить домен на https://api3.getresponse360.pl/v3.

Примеры curl-запросов:

```
curl 'https://api3.getresponse360.pl/v3/accounts' -H 'X-Auth-Token: api-key 123123123' -H 'X-DOMAIN: email.domain.com'
```

И на добавление контакта:

```
curl -k -H 'X-Auth-Token: api-key 11122233' -H "X-Domain: email.domain.ru" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"name":"Test","email":"test@domain.ru","campaign": {"campaignId":"campaignId"}}' 'https://api3.getresponse360.pl/v3/contacts'
```

Answer (score 0):

Несколько раз уже сталкивался на локальном сервере на Denwer, что CURL не срабатывает. Так же и с этим  https://github.com/GetResponse/getresponse-api-php
Решением всегда было задать для CURL:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
```